# Receive xmpp messages in command line

Tags: command-line, xmpp

Is there a command line tool, that can receive xmpp messages? I have used "sendxmpp". It is a small CLI tool to send xmpp messages. Is there a similar too receive xmpp messages? My intention is to run a tool(as a daemon preferably ) that can receive xmpp messages, and reply back via "sendxmpp". I have heard about profanity. But for my requirement, even 'profanity' seems to be bloated and I can't run it as a daemon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where/how should it output the messages if it runs as daemon?

Comment: I'd like process/parse the messages via some shell script. My idea is to have a script that can receive XMPP messages and reply back via sendxmpp.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a daemon to run, you could write an XMPP client which connects to the server and responds to messages.  Basically, you can write your own command line program.

I had success with python-jabberbot, specifically by extending this example:

https://github.com/averstappen/python-jabberbot/blob/master/examples/uptime.py